# Check box Click Method issue ( similar xpath) - WebDriver using java

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

two different Div's inside the Div have an check box, so i want to click the checkbox (i.e inside the "divPatPortfolioStatusCount"), both checkbox xpath are similar

```
(i.e By.xpath("//input[@accesskey='2']")
```

Html Code

```
<div id="divCreatePortfolio" class="wrapper">
<table class="adminlistfilter" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr data-bind="if: RowCounts>0, attr: {PortfolioId: Id, DescName:Name}" portfolioid="2" descname="Client-Default">
<td style="width: 5%;">
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { accesskey: Id }" accesskey="2">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="divPatPortfolioStatusCount" class="wrapper">
<table class="adminlistfilter" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr data-bind="if: RowCounts>0, attr: {StatusId: Id, DescName:Name}" statusid="2" descname="Abandoned">
<td style="width: 5%;">
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { accesskey: Id }" accesskey="2">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

my Java code

```
WebElement statusDiv= driver.findElement(By.id("divPatPortfolioStatusCount"));
WebElement checkBox = statusDiv.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@accesskey='2']"));
checkBox.click();
```

while executing under the "divCreatePortfolio" checkbox only checked not for "divPatPortfolioStatusCount" let me know the problem with my xpath

Answer (score 1):

You need click on those 2 different check box separately as below right?

```
//To check Status checkbox
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divCreatePortfolio']//input")).click();
//To check Status count checkbox
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divPatPortfolioStatusCount']//input")).click();
```

Comment: thanks, but assume it have 'n' number of checkbox means each div how  its possible with above xpath (checkbox was dynamic) so only i frame the xpath with id (i.e accesskey="2")

Comment: no particular Checkbox , depends on my test script,

Comment: Then pass the "div" id as parameter to click on required checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `css` and `nth-child()` function and control `child index` from test

```
body>div:nth-child(1) input
body>div:nth-child(2) input
```

Changing the number of `nth-child(1)` from `1` to `2` will find consecutive check boxes

Answer (score 0):

update the xpath in my code

```
WebElement statusTable = driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("//*[@id='divPatPortfolioStatusCount']/table/tbody"));
        List<WebElement> rows = statusTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            WebElement checkBoxSts = driver
                    .findElement(By
                            .xpath("//*[@id='divPatPortfolioStatusCount']/table/tbody/tr["
                                    + i + "]"));
            String statusAccessKey = checkBoxSts.getAttribute("statusid");

            if (statusAccessKey.equals(portfolioId)) {
                WebElement checkbox = driver
                        .findElement(By
                                .xpath("//*[@id='divPatPortfolioStatusCount']/table/tbody/tr["
                                        + i + "]/td[1]/input"));
                checkbox.click();
                break;
            }           
        }
```

collect the statusid from database with respective of status and pass the statusid in this method with parameter, and proceed

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as :

```
List<WebElements> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@accesskey='2']"));
for (WebElement web : lst)
    if(!web.isSelected())
        web.click();
```

And if you want to select input based on div id u can use:

```
//div[@id='divPatPortfolioStatusCount']//input
```

Comment: the solution is for if u want to check all checkboxes with xpath: //input[@accesskey='2']